# Add Azure Storage Blob Container input binding Azure Functions Java

Tags: azure-functions, azure-java-sdk

I have a EventHubTriggered Function app.Here is the code sample of the method signature:

@FunctionName("foo")
@StorageAccount("foostorageread")
public HttpResponseMessage run(
@HttpTrigger(
name = "req",
methods = {HttpMethod.POST},
authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS) HttpRequestMessage<Optional> request,
@BlobInput(
name = "{test1}",
dataType = "string",
path = "blobStorageContainer/{test1}.json") String test1,

```
        @BlobInput(
                  name = "test2", 
                  dataType = "string", 
                  path = "blobStorageContainer/{test2}.json") String test2,
       
        final ExecutionContext context)
```

I want to add the input binding to CloudBlobContainer(blobStorageContainer in the method signature above) in the method signature so that I do not need to explicitly connect to this container in my method (as I'll need to access more files from this container).  Is there any annotations/ways I can do that in Java?

Answer (score 0):

I followed the [blog](https://soltisweb.com/blog/detail/2020-06-09-workingwithazurestorageblobsinajavaazurefunction) to connect the Blob Storage container to get files.

Please refer a below code to use the `CloudBlobContainer` to connect the container and create the new container if it not exist in a blob.

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccountDest;
CloudBlobClient blobClientDest = null;
CloudBlobContainer containerDest = null;
String storageConnectionStringDest = System.getenv("AzureStorageDemoConnectionStringDest");

// Parse the connection string and create a blob client to interact with Blob
// storage
storageAccountDest = CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionStringDest);
blobClientDest = storageAccountDest.createCloudBlobClient();  
containerDest = blobClientDest.getContainerReference("files2");

// Create the container if it does not exist with public access.
context.getLogger().info("Creating container: " + containerDest.getName());
containerDest.createIfNotExists(BlobContainerPublicAccessType.CONTAINER, new BlobRequestOptions(),
new OperationContext());
CloudBlob blobDest = containerDest.getBlockBlobReference(filename);
try {
    context.getLogger().info("Start Uploading blob: " + filename);
    blobDest.uploadFromByteArray(content, 0, content.length);
    context.getLogger().info("Finished Uploading blob: " + filename);
} 
catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Please have a look [here](https://github.com/uglide/azure-content/blob/master/articles/storage/storage-java-how-to-use-blob-storage.md)

Answer (score 0):

Binding is done on a single blob object not whole storage account/container.
The reason is that the function expects a [concrete blob object(as some bytes)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-input?tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-java).

Eventually you can add multiple separate bindings and use [binding expressions](https://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-expressions-patterns). This can work if you have a fixed set of filenames.